# Migration TFS 2015 to VSTS

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015

I'm trying to migrate my code source on VSTS.

I use the migration Guide by Microsoft and I am block on step 4 "Validate Your TFS Server". I must use TFS Migrator's tool by commande line.

1) If I unzip the tool on a folder in `c:\Temp` and I put my commandLine :
`TfsMigrator Validate /Collection:http://be-pop-src5:8080/tfs/Project2015` I have this error:

> TF255003: The installation patch cannot be found for the following
>   feature: ApplicationTier. Either the feature is not installed, or you
>   must use a different installation path.

2) If I unzip the tool on a folder in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools` and I put my CommandLine: 
`TfsMigrator Validate /Collection:http://be-pop-src5:8080/tfs/Project2015` I have this error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common,
>   Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or
>   one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition
>   does not match the assembly reference.

Someone can help me ?

Comment: Do you clear it?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the [documentation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=54274). TFS 2015 is not a supported platform for migration to VSTS.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the offcial article: [Migrate data from TFS to VSTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/articles/migration-overview#supported-tfs-versions-for-import), currently the following version(s) of TFS are supported for import is/are TFS 2017 Update2.

So you need to upgrade TFS 2015 to TFS 2017 update 2 first, then migrate to VSTS. There is a blog about [upgrade to TFS 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2016/11/30/upgrade-to-team-foundation-server-tfs-2017/).